# Oracle global temporary tables leaves behind empty tables

Tags: oracle, temp-tables

I am trying to create some temporary table with this code

```
   CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE EMAIL_NEW
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
AS

SELECT
  CUSTOMER_ID

FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE  
;
```

I was expecting the table to disappear after I close the connection, but when I reconnect there's an empty table still there. Now I have a bunch of empty temporary tables cluttering up my space. What do I need to do differently to make the tables disappear completely?

Comment: Oracle temporary tables are "temporary" with respect to the data in them, not the table's lifespan.  This is not like SQLServer temp tables(#).  If you want to remove the table later on, you need to drop it.

Comment: You need `create private temporary table`, not `global`, and this is a [new feature in Oracle 18c](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/private-temporary-tables-18c).